# Creating Line Plot with Diverging Coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I'm trying to create a line plot with a diverging colormap, and I'm facing some challenges.

My goal is to produce a line plot that effectively visualizes data using a diverging colormap. However, despite my best efforts, I'm still grappling with the implementation.

Here's what I've attempted:

1. I've imported the necessary libraries (e.g., Matplotlib, Seaborn).
2. I've prepared my data for the line plot.
3. I've set up the basic line plot structure.

**In explaining in a simple way, I have two columns data-frame, one is date(x-axis), other is y-axis values, I want to create a line plot, it should look like the below attached picture, the diverging color according to values.**

But I'm struggling to apply a diverging colormap to the plot. I've tried different approaches, but I'm not getting the results I want.

If you have experience with creating line plots with diverging colormaps in Python, I'd greatly appreciate your insights and advice!

I want the output graph looks like this attached graph in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the image, but does this example help? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

Comment: It would also be really helpful if you provide the code for what you tried, and explain why the output is not what you want.

Comment: Please check again, there was an error while attaching image. The code you've shared, I want like the above graph the diverging of colour bar.

Answer (score 1):

in matplotlib you can't draw multicolor line using standart plot method, instead you can use LineCollection with segments

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

colors = np.array(y)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('RdBu')

norm = Normalize(min(y), max(y))

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(colors)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(min(y), 1.05 * max(y))
ax.set_xlim(min(x), 1.05 * max(x))
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image]